# How to use multiple confirm dialogs using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello i want to put multiple confirm dialog on click of a button,
Ex. when i click a button it shows "Are you sure?" with YES and NO, when i click YES another dialog box has to open with "want to notify users?" with YES and NO

```
<script>
 $('.deletes').click( function () {  
if (confirm( 'Are you sure? ' ) ) {  
window.location="<?php echo site_url('controller/method'); ?>";
if (confirm( 'want to notify users? ' ) )
{ 
window.location="<?php echo site_url('contoller/method22'); ?>";
} 

} });


</script>
```

Comment: Confirm box inside a confirm box.

Comment: Ok.. Have you tried anything?

Comment: no i haven't tried,not inside,when i click yes in first confirm dialog then it has to close and next dialog has to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code to redirect user after multiple confirmation

step 1- add following line in html file

```
<button id='open_dialog'>click</button>
```

step 2- Add following line to the js file-

```
jQuery('#open_dialog').click( function () {

    if (confirm( 'Are you sure? ' ) ) {

        if (confirm( 'want to notify users? ' ) ) {
            //use statement to redirect on particular page.
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be better if you put the code you have so far, anyway see example below :

```
$('button').click( function () { 
  // first box, if yes then enter if block  
  if (confirm( 'Are you sure? ' ) ) {  
    // again came out 2nd box      
    if (confirm( 'want to notify users? ' ) ) {
        // do something
    }
 }    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/sv1e71qc/)

Comment: this is what i want exactly,thanks..can i link to a function on next click,that is when i click yes in want to notify customer? a message has to  go,so how to pass it to function

Comment: Just call the function inside second if block, then you're good to go.

Comment: What function, js function or CI function ?

Comment: CI function to be called for sending a message

Comment: You can use AJAX to call that, can you update your question with CI function

Comment: this `window.location="<?php echo site_url('contoller/method22'); ?>";` ,code will redirect into page. What the problem with this?